# I need to encrypt existing pdf file with password protect without qpdf in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, encryption, passwords, password-protection

I need to encrypt existing pdf file with password protected when the pdf file is tried to open it should ask for password please anyone provide solution without using qpdf in nodejs
I need the solution for password protect pdf file using nodejs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not willing to call out to a command line tool, you can do this with in pure JS with coherentpdf.js, which is AGPL-licensed: https://github.com/coherentgraphics/coherentpdf.js

For example (untested):

```
const coherentpdf = require('./coherentpdf.js');
var pdf = coherentpdf.fromFile('in.pdf', '');
var permissions = [coherentpdf.noEdit];
cpdf.toFileEncrypted(pdf, coherentpdf.aes256bitisofalse, permissions, 'ownerpw', 'userpw', false, false, 'out.pdf');
```